# How to fix error "E: Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop"?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install Lunar ROS for Uduntu on Dell Inspiron 300 laptop.
Keep getting:

"E: Unable to locate package ros-lunar-desktop"

Followed these instructions from ROS lunar site:

1. sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
2. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-desktop-full

Also tried smaller lunars, but they gave same error.  Also, tried:
apt-cache search ros-lunar

To check, to no avail.

Looked up similar issues but solutions were not specific to this issue.

Tried on a different laptop, same model and getting same issue.

New to linux and need help with solution install of lunar ROS please.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281943/how-to-fix-error-%22e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-desktop%22?/) by [buckleti](https://answers.ros.org/users/33593/buckleti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-06**:
Which OS is this? And which version? Can you add the output of `lsb_release -a` to your question? Use the `edit` button/link.

**Comment by [buckleti](https://answers.ros.org/users/33593/buckleti/) on 2018-02-06**:
Output of lsb_releas -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
Description:      Ubuntu 17.10
Release:           17.10
Codename:       artful

OS =  Ubuntu
Version = 17.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 17.10 is not a supported platform for Lunar. See [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019) It only support 16.04, 16.10, and 17.04.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buckleti](https://answers.ros.org/users/33593/buckleti/) on 2018-02-06**:
Thank you very much!   I see 17.04 no longer exists (end of life).  Any suggestions as to which I should install that will work. This is my first time and I would like to make sure it works with ROS on my system.  Thanks again!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-02-06**:
I'd recommend Xenial 16.04 the LTS Ubuntu release

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-02-06**:
Please accept the question (using the checkmark to the left) so others know it's been answered.